# How to prevent BitBucket credentials getting stored in Windows Credential Manager when using Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, bitbucket, credential-manager

I can't stop my BitBucket credentials being stored in Windows Credential Manager when using Visual Studio.

I've unset `credential.helper` using all three commands:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git config --system --unset credential.helper
git config --unset credential.helper
```

Interestingly, after running the above commands the `credential.helper` setting still shows `manager` within Visual Studio repository settings.

I've even tried disabling Credential Manager within Windows Services but all this does is prevent me from opening Credential Manager. The credentials are still getting stored!

I've also tried setting `credential.helper` to `cache --timeout=600` hoping that the credentials would be forgotten after 10 minutes. But still the credentials are stored, and remembered after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a way of doing it so now I just use `Git Bash` instead.

I need to do this as I'm using a shared virtual machine and can't have my personal credentials stored there.